# I mixed two stories in a story-identification question. Found one of them. What do I do now?

Tags: support, story-identification

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120508/16171) I initially had two story plots mixed together. I've since discovered this error and know one of the stories but not the other. Do I now:

- leave this alone and wait for an answer
- edit the found story out of the question
- delete the question and start over
- a fourth thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We typically don't like it when an edit invalidates existing answers. But your question doesn't have any existing answers, so this is pretty straightforward. I would recommend the following:

- Edit the elements of the unknown story out of the question
- ***Answer the question with the story you know, and accept the answer.***
- Post a second story-id question with the elements of the unknown story

To my mind, this arrangement will give you the highest chance of getting a good answer to the question you actually have, while also letting the site at large benefit from the knowledge you've obtained.